# FPS <30 in all games on Rx 480

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, gaming, fps

Guys  I don't even know where to start so maybe I will give my spec first:

Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 MOBO

Aerocool 750W 80+ Bronze PSU

AMD FX 8320 octo-core 3.50GHZ CPU

16GB 1600 MHZ RAM

1TB SATA HDD

Win 10 x64

Samsung Monitor 1080p

Sapphire Nitro+ OC RX 480 8GB graphics

The graphics card is the newest addition. Although I know 8320 is an old CPU Ive had a comprehensive research before making the decision (so I thought), checked a lot of Youtube Videos with people showing FPS on modern games on that CPU, checked compatibility issues. All worked fine.

The term thrown a lot is "bottlenecking" however I am no IT expert and again most people across the net said that CPU wont cap the card. So I bought it, installed it and started playing games.

Now my issue is that the range of FPS is huuge. Let's take GTA5. I will get sudden drops from 60+ FPS to 27. and it happens frequently and a lot.

Second problem is the fact that no matter the graphics preset I get more or less the same FPS. I can play with all the Graphics on VERY HIGH and the FPS will be the same on NORMAL. The most annoying thing is that it drops below 30 all the time, and when that happens the game stutter and you can't play. I am not expecting having constant 60 FPS on ultra but at least 40+ on High.

For a comparison I can give you a game Watch Dogs and same thing happens, the game will drop to below 30 no matter what the settings are.

I feel like there is something going on here that caps my card. I could get the same FPS with my old 2gb 750 Ti. I know I probably didn't give too much information but if someone is willing to spend a while on my case and knows something more about PCs then I am willing to provide necessary information. At the moment I am feeling like I thrown away £250 and that is a lot for me.

The most worrying things let me rephrase are:

-Massive range of FPS and sudden drops

-FPS not changing significantly when changing Graphics Quality on the game

-FPS dropping below 30.

Regards.

Comment: Throttling due to Overheating? Background Scheduled Tasks? Power Saver mode?

Comment: Check the temperature

Comment: do you have V-sync enabled and only 30Hz refresh rate (4K display)?

Comment: try latest AMD driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-ReLive-Edition-17.1.2-Release-Notes.aspx